# Parsing Calendar blob from Oracle Primavera using Javascript

Tags: javascript, calendar, primavera

Oracle Primavera stores Calendar data as blob in base64 encoded format, which when decoded gives the following content,

> (0||CalendarData()(  (0||DaysOfWeek()(    (0||1()())    (0||2()(      (0||0(s|08:00|f|16:00)())))    (0||3()(      (0||0(s|08:00|f|16:00)())))    (0||4()(      (0||0(s|08:00|f|16:00)())))    (0||5()(      (0||0(s|08:00|f|16:00)())))    (0||6()(      (0||0(s|08:00|f|16:00)())))    (0||7()())))  (0||VIEW(ShowTotal|Y)())  (0||Exceptions()(    (0||0(d|39814)())    (0||1(d|39815)())    (0||2(d|39818)())    (0||3(d|39819)())    (0||4(d|39820)())    (0||5(d|39821)())    (0||6(d|39822)())    (0||7(d|39825)())    (0||8(d|39826)())    (0||9(d|39827)())    (0||10(d|39828)())    (0||11(d|39829)())    (0||12(d|39832)())    (0||13(d|39833)())    (0||14(d|39834)())    (0||15(d|39835)())    (0||16(d|39836)())    (0||17(d|39839)())    (0||18(d|39840)())    (0||19(d|39841)())    (0||20(d|39842)())    (0||21(d|39843)())    (0||22(d|39846)())    (0||23(d|39847)())    (0||24(d|39848)())    (0||25(d|39849)())    (0||26(d|39850)())    (0||27(d|39853)())    (0||28(d|39854)())    (0||29(d|39855)())    (0||30(d|39856)())    (0||31(d|39857)())    (0||32(d|39860)())    (0||33(d|39861)())    (0||34(d|39862)())    (0||35(d|39863)())    (0||36(d|39864)())    (0||37(d|39867)())    (0||38(d|39868)())    (0||39(d|39869)())    (0||40(d|39870)())    (0||41(d|39871)())    (0||42(d|39874)())    (0||43(d|39875)())    (0||44(d|39876)())    (0||45(d|39877)())    (0||46(d|39878)())    (0||47(d|39881)())    (0||48(d|39882)())    (0||49(d|39883)())    (0||50(d|39884)())    (0||51(d|39885)())    (0||52(d|39888)())    (0||53(d|39889)())    (0||54(d|39890)())    (0||55(d|39891)())    (0||56(d|39892)())    (0||57(d|39895)())    (0||58(d|39896)())    (0||59(d|39897)())    (0||60(d|39898)())    (0||61(d|39899)())    (0||62(d|39902)())    (0||63(d|39903)())    (0||64(d|39923)())    (0||65(d|39958)())    (0||66(d|39997)())    (0||67(d|40063)())    (0||68(d|40098)())    (0||69(d|40128)())    (0||70(d|40133)())    (0||71(d|40134)())    (0||72(d|40135)())    (0||73(d|40136)())    (0||74(d|40137)())    (0||75(d|40140)())    (0||76(d|40141)())    (0||77(d|40142)())    (0||78(d|40143)())    (0||79(d|40144)())    (0||80(d|40147)())    (0||81(d|40148)())    (0||82(d|40149)())    (0||83(d|40150)())    (0||84(d|40151)())    (0||85(d|40154)())    (0||86(d|40155)())    (0||87(d|40156)())    (0||88(d|40157)())    (0||89(d|40158)())    (0||90(d|40161)())    (0||91(d|40162)())    (0||92(d|40163)())    (0||93(d|40164)())    (0||94(d|40165)())    (0||95(d|40168)())    (0||96(d|40169)())    (0||97(d|40170)())    (0||98(d|40171)())    (0||99(d|40172)())    (0||100(d|40175)())    (0||101(d|40176)())    (0||102(d|40177)())    (0||103(d|40178)())    (0||104(d|40179)())    (0||105(d|40182)())    (0||106(d|40183)())    (0||107(d|40184)())    (0||108(d|40185)())    (0||109(d|40186)())    (0||110(d|40189)())    (0||111(d|40190)())    (0||112(d|40191)())    (0||113(d|40192)())    (0||114(d|40193)())    (0||115(d|40196)())    (0||116(d|40197)())    (0||117(d|40198)())    (0||118(d|40199)())    (0||119(d|40200)())    (0||120(d|40203)())    (0||121(d|40204)())    (0||122(d|40205)())    (0||123(d|40206)())    (0||124(d|40207)())    (0||125(d|40210)())    (0||126(d|40211)())    (0||127(d|40212)())    (0||128(d|40213)())    (0||129(d|40214)())    (0||130(d|40217)())    (0||131(d|40218)())   .....

How can I read the dates from this variable ? I need to convert it into JSON to be used by the script. I need all the exceptions - the value and date ( For instance, 131 is the exception and 40218 is the date ). Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MPXJ reads this data. The relevant code can be found starting here https://github.com/joniles/mpxj/blob/master/src/net/sf/mpxj/primavera/PrimaveraReader.java#L181 which I suspect you can translate easily enough into Javascript.

Comment: Thank you. Regex is the only option it seems. I managed to do it with regex global match. Your link above is useful.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did this in PHP
Parse the data with a nested parenthesis class

https://gist.github.com/Xeoncross/4710324

Then deal with the time intervals

```
if( preg_match('~^s\|([0-9]+):([0-9]+)\|f\|([0-9]+):([0-9]+)$~', $string, $match) )
{   // Start and finish times
    $interval[] = array(
        's' => array(
            't' => $match[1].':'.$match[2],
            'h' => (int)$match[1],
            'm' => (int)$match[2],
        ),
        'f' => array(
            't' => $match[3].':'.$match[4],
            'h' => (int)$match[3],
            'm' => (int)$match[4],
        )
    );
}
```